# CFFI Not Loading Dependent Libraries?

Tags: windows, common-lisp, sbcl, blas, cffi

I am trying to use the BLAS/LAPACK libraries from SBCL (specifically trying to get the [LLA](https://github.com/tpapp/lla) package running).  I was having a lot of troubles getting the BLAS shared library to load; eventually I discovered that it wasn't able to load its dependent libraries. Eventually I was able to load BLAS by loaded all of its dependencies manually:

```
(setq cffi::*foreign-library-directories* '("C:/cygwin64/bin/" "C:/cygwin64/lib/lapack/"))
(CFFI:LOAD-FOREIGN-LIBRARY "CYGWIN1.DLL")
(CFFI:LOAD-FOREIGN-LIBRARY "CYGGCCC_S-SEH-1.DLL")
[..etc..]
(CFFI:LOAD-FOREIGN-LIBRARY "CYGBLAS-0.dll")
```

As a workaround this isn't terrible, but I don't understand why CFFI:LOAD-FOREIGN-LIBRARY is not able to find and load the dependencies itself.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case it's probably not CFFI but [Windows DLL search rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx) that make this happen.

As `cygblas-0.dll` is in the `c:\cygwin64\lib\lapack` directory, any dependencies it may have are searched from that same directory, the current directory, Windows directories, and from `PATH`.

If you do not have `c:\cygwin64\bin` in your path, the DLLs cannot be found. `cffi::*foreing-library-directories*` does not affect the Windows functionality; CFFI simply executes a call to [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with a full path to the DLL.

As a solution, I suggest you configure your `PATH` to include the `c:\cygwin64\bin` directory, which is a good idea in any case. Alternatively, you could modify the `PATH` environment variable in your code before the call to `load-foreign-library`, but [the way it's done is implementation dependent](http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/os.html#env).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I had assumed that adding directories to the cffi:*foreign-library-directories* would add them to the load search path, but if not that would explain the problem.